Flutter FCM Send
I have a Flutter app with Firebase Cloud Messaging. Basically, it links a user document to an FCM device token. The plan was that every time a user would send a message to a chat or group chat, on that very same send method, another method like this one would be called:
static void sendNotificationToUsers(
  {required List<String> recepients,
  required String title,
  required Map<String, String> payload}) {
for (String to in recepients) {
  _fcm.sendMessage(
    to: to,
    data: payload,
  );
}

}
The problem is .sendMessage is deprecated. It's being removed in June of 2024! I saw this article about migrating to a different API. So I kept firebase_messaging: ^14.9.1 on my pubspec.yaml for its token functionality, and also added on firebase_cloud_messaging_flutter, which has you throw in your json credentials and then starts a 'server'. If I were to replace _fcm.sendMessage in my code above, it would look something like this:
//We create the FCM server up here
//servviceAccountFileContent contains my credentials
final fcmServer = FirebaseCloudMessagingServer(
  serviceAccountFileContent,
);

//Then we send the notification
var result = await fcmServer.send(
    FirebaseSend(
      validateOnly: false,
      message: FirebaseMessage(
        notification: FirebaseNotification(
          title: title,
          body: 'body',
        ),
        data: payload,
        android: const FirebaseAndroidConfig(
          ttl: '3s',

          /// Add Delay in String. If you want to add 1 minute delat then add it like "60s"
          notification: FirebaseAndroidNotification(
            icon: 'ic_notification',
            color: '#009999',
          ),
        ),
        token: to,
      ),
    ),
  );

Is having many instances of a 'server' sustainable for many users messaging each other? Is it scalable? Is it 'good practice' to allow every user to make use of my project credentials? And if not, what's the alternative?
Thanks in advance everyone, hope you have a good day.

 Including the service account details of your project in the application that you send to your users is an incredible security risk. These credentials can be used to gain full administrative access to your project. Please don't ever do this. 

In general calls to the FCM REST API are required to specify credentials that should only every be used in a trusted environment. The reason for this is that anyone who has such credentials can send whatever message they want to all of your users - which is also a security risk.
See How to send one to one message using Firebase Messaging for a better solution.

Thanks Frank, your answer was super helpful. While I have you, I'd like to ask, what's the difference between having an API key in my app and having those json credentials? Isn't it equally as safe? Don't they both just get crunched into binary on compilation anyway?

It depends a bit on the specific API key, but in most Firebase products we use API keys only to identify a service - not to authorize your usage. See for more on this https://stackoverflow.com/q/37482366. The JSON credentials that the firebase_cloud_messaging_flutter package tells you to include grant full administrative access to your project, so it's like you're adding everyone as an owner to your GCP project. If billing is enabled, they could add VMs, enable more services, etc - all on your bill.
